# problema en diseño de tablas contable y Error de Foreign key

Tags: javascript, mysql, base-de-datos, php5, diseño

Buenas noches

Estoy haciendo un sistema contable y debo guardar una declaracion contable que puede tener N cargos y N abonos (hay catalogos de ambas cosas), al crear los foreigh key de la tabla declaracion, me marca error al querer apuntar a dichos catalogos. ¿Cómo los puedo relacionar?

Por otro lado ¿Cómo puedo guardar y relacionar N cargos y N abonos que se relacionan entre si y que cambian en cada declaracion?

Es decir, en la imagen ponen un ejemplo de una declaracion, pero en la realidad, un abono puede ser pagado con N cargos y puede haber N abonos. Pensaba hacerlo en una sola tabla pero no me queda.

Agrego el codigo mysql de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE SDC.declaracion (
    idDecl INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    operacion NUMERIC(14) NOT NULL,
    numCaso NUMERIC(14) NOT NULL,
    idCargo1 varchar(6),
    impCargo1 NUMERIC(10),
    idAbono1 varchar(6),
    impAbono1 NUMERIC(10),
    idCargo2 varchar(6),
    impCargo2 NUMERIC(10),
    idAbono2 varchar(6),
    impAbono2 NUMERIC(10), 

    CONSTRAINT pkIdDecl
    PRIMARY KEY(idDecl,operacion, numCaso), 

    CONSTRAINT fk_declaracion_cargo
    FOREIGN KEY (idCargo1)
    REFERENCES cargo(idCargo),

    CONSTRAINT fk_declaracion_abono
    FOREIGN KEY (idAbono1)
    REFERENCES abono(idAbono)
);
```

```html
CREATE TABLE SDC.abono (
 idAbono NUMERIC(6),
 conceptoAbono VARCHAR (100),

 CONSTRAINT pkIdAbono
 PRIMARY KEY(idAbono));

CREATE TABLE SDC.cargo (
 idCargo NUMERIC(6),
 conceptoCargo VARCHAR (100),

 CONSTRAINT pkIdCargo
 PRIMARY KEY(idCargo));
```

[image: Este es un ejemplo de lo que va a contener el catálogo de abonos]

[image: Este es un ejemplo de lo que va a contener el catálogo de cargos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir la estructura de tus tablas abono y cargo por favor?

Comment: Yikarus ya añadí el código a la pregunta, los cinco catálogos son iguales: con id y descripcion como unicos campos. Gracias!

Comment: Cual es el error que te manda al querer hacer las fk?

Comment: Yikarus
Me marca este error:
#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `sdc`.`declaracion` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Pero el verdadero problema es el diseño, es decir, como meter N cargos y N abonos

Comment: Estás violando una norma básica de las llaves primarias/foráneas: **ambas columnas deben tener el mismo tipo de datos**. Si por ejemplo `idAbono1 varchar(6)` la declaras como clave foránea relacionada con `idAbono NUMERIC(6)`... ¡Error! una es `VARCHAR` y la otra es `NUMERIC`. Por otra parte, yo cuando veo en una misma tabla nombres de columnas con el mismo nombre, enumaradas como `idAbono, idAbono1, idAbono2...` intuyo que es casi seguro que haya un error de diseño. Tienes muchos casos así, quizá necesites otra tabla y manejar relaciones en ella o una columna del tipo `ENUM`.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, efectivamente cometí un error al declarar los tipos de datos de esas columnas.
Efectivamente tengo un problema de diseño porque debo guardar una declaracion que puede tener N cargos y N abonos; ¿me puedes explicar mejor cómo resolver eso?

Answer (score 1):

[Lo resolví así](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPaQX.png), espero que mi modelado esté bien.

Actualización:

Debido a que un cargo puede tener varios abonos, es necesario agregar una llave en la tabla de abonos, que indique a que cargo pertenece. Igualmente, existe una relación de 1 a 1 entre los cargos / conceptos y abonos, por lo que he agregado una tabla adicional **conceptos** en donde podrás registrar el nombre del concepto y el tipo del concepto (tipos de ejemplo, cargos, abonos, etc)....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_1`.`declaracion` (
  `idDecl` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `operacion` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `numCaso` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDecl`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_1`.`cargo` (
  `idCargo` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDecl` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `idConcepto` INT NULL,
  `Subtotal` DECIMAL(20,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Impuestos` DECIMAL(20,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total` DECIMAL(20,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCargo`),
  INDEX `fk_cargo_decl_id_idx` (`idDecl` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_cargo_concep_id_idx` (`idConcepto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cargo_decl_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`idDecl`)
REFERENCES `db_1`.`declaracion` (`idDecl`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cargo_concep_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`idConcepto`)
REFERENCES `db_1`.`conceptos` (`idConcepto`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_1`.`abono` (
  `idAbono` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDecl` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCargo` INT NULL,
  `idConcepto` INT NULL,
  `Subtotal` DECIMAL(20,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Impuestos` DECIMAL(20,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total` DECIMAL(20,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAbono`),
  INDEX `fk_abono_decl_id_idx` (`idDecl` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_abono_cargo_id_idx` (`idCargo` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_abono_concep_id_idx` (`idConcepto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_abono_decl_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`idDecl`)
REFERENCES `db_1`.`declaracion` (`idDecl`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_abono_cargo_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`idCargo`)
REFERENCES `db_1`.`cargo` (`idCargo`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_abono_concep_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`idConcepto`)
REFERENCES `db_1`.`conceptos` (`idConcepto`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_1`.`conceptos` (
  `idConcepto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Tipo` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idConcepto`));
```

> Quisiera sugerirte algunos cambios a tu script para la creación de tu
>   tabla y trataré de explicar el porque.
>
> 1. En tu enunciado mencionas que una **declaración** puede tener **N cargos** y **N abonos**. Viendo la estructura de creación de la tabla
>      declaración, estas limitado a tener sólo dos **cargos** y dos
>      **abonos** (idCargo1, idCargo2, idAbono1, idAbono2). Al momento de existir tercer abono o un tercer cargo, tendrás que cambiar la
>      estructura de la tabla.
> 2. Para poder lograr el enunciado de tu descripción (1 declaración puede tener N cargos y abonos), deberías cambiar las estructuras de
>      las tres tablas para que las tablas **abonos** y **cargos** tengan un
>      ID que identifique a cual declaración pertenecen.
>
> De esta manera, podrás tener la cantidad de abonos y cargos que sean
>   requeridos sin necesidad de realizar cambios en el futuro.
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agradezco la sugerencia, solo tengo una duda: ¿Cómo relacionaria de esa manera los conceptos de los cargos y abonos (los catálogos) para obtener algo como el ejemplo (que por cierto, es mucho mas simple que el objetivo final puesto que cada cargo puede ser pagado con N abonos y puede haber abonos en la misma declaración que paguen 2 o más cargos)

Comment: Con lo que dices, es mismo concepto. Una declaración puede tener N cargos, y Un cargo, puede tener N abonos. Sobre los catálogos de conceptos para abonos y cargos, la relación sería de uno a uno, es decir, un cargo tiene un concepto, un abono, tiene un concepto

Comment: Gracias Javier, así como lo tengo ahora, cargo y abono no tienen relación porque sólo son catálogos que proveen la clave a declaración, entre ellos no hay reglas de negocio para que se relacionen y es precisamente esa la razón por la que tengo problema de diseño, porque no se cómo hacer para guardar los cargos y abonos cuando los ingresen

Comment: Yo veo q al momento que un usuario o proceso automático cree una declaración, deberá generar cargos. Si es un proceso automático, este  debe insertar un registro en la tabla "DECLARACION" y con el nuevo ID, obtener los registros de la tabla CONCEPTOS (tipo "CARGO"), crear registros en la tabla CARGO, utilizando el ID declaración y IDs de los conceptos. Así cada cargo tiene su concepto y su declaración.

Comment: Al momento que venga un cliente a pagar la declaración XYZ, el usuario deberá buscar la declaración y el sistema deberá buscar todos los registros de la tabla CARGO, que estén relacionados a la declaración XYZ. El usuario deberá seleccionar los cargos a pagar y registrar en la tabla ABONO el pago del cliente.